# Python: Create a list based on elements on text and extracting specific values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-extraction

I have the following text:

`mytext = '2/3/4/5/6/'`

In python, I need to create a list or a dictionary with values on this text, extracting the number between "/", but excluding the last one.

The final result should be something like:

`myresult = ['2', '3', '4', '5']`

Thank you in advance

Comment: where's the dictionary?

Comment: As a result you have a list with a set inside instead of a dictionary. Is this what you want? You can do `[set(mytext.split('/')[:-1])]` which will return you `[{'3', '5', '6', '2', '4'}]` But why do you want it inside a list of only 1 element?

Comment: @enke, as per my request, "list or a dictionary". thank you

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, thank you. Only one element just for simplify the sample I gave. Tested with -2 instead of -1 and worked as expected. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mytext.split('/')[:-2]
```

This should work to create a list for the given format.

Comment: The answer from Sembei Norimaki also help me achieve what I want. Thank you @Akash Cherukuri